# How to solve 403 error with iframe in MAMP

Tags: apache, iframe, mamp, http-status-code-403, cross-origin-read-blocking

Thank you in advance for your help.

I'm trying to figure what is the problem with a 403 error i got with an iframe embedded in the website I'm building with MAMP. This iframe is from another website and i pass it through my website with a script tag.

I first thought about cross-origin problem but even if its showing an error for this, its working when i past the script tag in a random html page that i open on my browser.
So i think its Apache configuration that cause this issue.
I tried first to delete the

```
Header set X-Frame-Options
```

in the httpd.conf file. But i dont find this line at all.

Then i looked for this

```
<Directory />
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

Changing from All to None and reverse but the iframe is still not showing.

Anybody as an idea of what I should do ? maybe `mod_security` ?